# Is the set $SL(2, \mathbb F)$ an Abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, matrices

For the set $SL(2,\mathbb F)$, where $\mathbb F$ are entries from either $$\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C} \text{ or } \mathbb{Z}_p \text{  (p is prime)}$$

How should I start by checking this matrix group is an Abelian group?

First off, what is modulo $p$ prime? (modulo integer n is the set of integers in the set smaller than n and relative prime to n so does modulo p prime implies the set of integers which are prime, smaller than n and relative prime to n? Doesn't make much sense to me)

Comment: HINT: if $T \in SL_2(\mathbb{F})$ and it is a group then $T$ must have an inverse. What does said inverse look like for some of the fields? Furthermore, just try commuting two matrices and see what you get!

Comment: @phatty For the inverse property to hold, the determinant of a matrix must be non-zero. Then it is obvious that a matrix A multiplied with it's inverse must equal the identity matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $SL(2,\mathbb F)$ is not an abelian group, because

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\ne
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much although I'd really like asking more. What is the definition of $$\mathbb{Z}_p$$?

Comment: @User Usually $\Bbb Z_p$ is short hand for $\Bbb Z / p \Bbb Z$ i.e. the quotient group(actually a ring since when $p$ prime, since $p\Bbb Z$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z$)) in which your familiar equivalence classes(cosets) for modular arithmetic take place. When $\Bbb Z_p$ is prime, the ring has all of its multiplicative inverses, and is hence a field, $\Bbb Z_p\cong \Bbb F_p$

Comment: @AlexClark I'm not familiar with $$\text{$\mathbb{Z}$/p$\mathbb{Z}$}$$

At the point of these notes given in lectures, Cosets were not taught and have not, but which would be.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z_p$ is a shorthand for $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. When $p$ is prime this defines a quotient ring, since $\Bbb Z$ is a ring and $p\Bbb Z$ defines an ideal of $\Bbb Z$. It turns out that $p\Bbb Z$ is a maximal ideal in $\Bbb Z$ and hence the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field, e.g. $\Bbb F_p$ the field of $p$ elements.

Now what does $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ mean in terms of how you will be dealing with it? Let $p=3$. Here you are dealing with modulo three arithmetic, e.g.

$$=2\pmod 3 + 4\pmod 3\equiv2\pmod3+1\pmod3$$$$2+4=6=0\pmod3$$

Now $\Bbb Z_p$ is an abelian group under addition regardless of whether we have $p$ prime or not, but when $p$ is not prime we don't have all of our multiplicative inverses. It is in this case that we have a monoid under multiplication. This monoid with our abelian group addition gives a ring.

So taking entries from $\Bbb Z_p$ $p$ prime, means to take entries from $\Bbb F_p$, here your matrices will be filled with values from $\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,p-1\}$.

Comment: So $$\mathbb{Z}_p$$ are all prime smaller than p? Although a contradiction arise since 0 is not a prime.

Comment: @user $\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z\cong \Bbb F_n$ only when $n$ is prime. The elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ are $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\cdots,n-1\}$ these need not be prime. You can verify that $(\Bbb Z_n,+)$ is an abelian group whether $n$ is prime or not and you can verify that $(\Bbb Z_n,\times)$ is an abelian group when $n$ is prime(but isn't when $n$ is not prime, in fact it is a monoid under multiplication)

Comment: The curly subscript is unfamiliar. I believe I've strayed off course from my notes. Will check back this page to fill in the gaps.
Thank you.

Comment: @user no problem, but if you have ever worked with $10\pmod {15}$, well to be informal here, that $15$ just means you are working with $\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z$ so when you have $\Bbb Z_p$ you are dealing with $x\pmod p$ where after reducing it mod $p$, $x$ is one of the elements in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,\cdots,p\}$

Comment: Thanks. 
One last question before I move on. 
I believe an assumption was made that this matrix is a group. But how do I check that this is a group? The usual check style I used for a simple set does not work here.

Comment: @User Same old thing, check identity, inverse, closure under operation and make sure you remember that your matrices need $\det 1$. Taking an arbitrary matrix, filling entries like:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$ can be informative when you are dealing with $2\times 2$ cases.

Comment: Thank you but since the operation is multiplicative modulo, is it necessary for me to apply this operation to each entries (more specifically, entries in the matrix greater than n and replace that entries with the remainder?)

Comment: @user I am super sure I understand, but as long as you reduce it at some point it is fine. It is just nicer to reduce it on the first step. It won't become wrong if you keep multiplying them without reducing them, otherwise the math wouldn't work. But reducing them first is best, like this(in $\Bbb Z_5$):

$$\begin{bmatrix}3&9\\3&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}6&1\\2&4\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}36&39\\26&19\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\equiv\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\1&4\end{bmatrix}\pmod {5}$$

(Note: by no means are these in SL, just an example)

Comment: Or reducing those matrices $\pmod 5$ *first* we get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\3&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&4\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}11&19\\11&19\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\equiv\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\1&4\end{bmatrix}\pmod 5$$